# mapstruct qualifiedByName without parameters simplify expression

Tags: java, optimization, mapping, mapstruct

I would like to set a constant on the field, but with method call, i do not want to create an expression it looks terrible, i would like to simplify this call

```
 @Mapping(target = "channelNotification", expression= "java(new ChannelNotification[]{ " +
                "new ChannelNotification(\"email\", 10)})")
```

to get something like this:

```
 @Mapping(target = "channel", qualifiedByName = "getChannel")
    Notification convert(Email emailEntity);

 @Named("getChannel")
    default Channel[] getChannel() {//with empty params
        return new Channel[]{new Channel("email", 10)};
    }
```

Source entity doesn't have field channelNotification, and i don't need to use it. I just want to set a constant like constant = *, but with method call

Answer (score 3):

You can do it without using `source` by a direct call of the required method via `expression`:

```
 @Mapping(target = "channel", expression = "java(getChannel())")
 Notification convert(Email emailEntity);
```

Looks like devellopers of `mapstruct` [do not want to support](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/3216#issuecomment-1594482937) the special feature for it.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible. However, what you can do is to use a combination of `constant` and `qualifiedByName`.

e.g.

```java
    @Mapping(target = "channel", constant = "email" qualifiedByName = "getChannel")
    Notification convert(Email emailEntity);

    @Named("getChannel")
    default Channel[] getChannel(String channelType) {
        Channel channel;
        if ("email".equals(channelType)) {
            channel = new Channel("email", 10);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown channel type " + channelType);
        }

        return new Channel[]{channel};
    }
```

What is not known that much is that `constant` works in a similar way with qualifiers as other `Mapping#source`. Since 1.4 custom mappings between `String` (what is in `constant`) and the target type will be looked for in order to convert the constant value.